# How to integrate PayUMoney(payu-non-seam-less-react) with expo react native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't integrate PayUMoney(payu-non-seam-less-react) with my expo react native app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RVIm.png)

Please help me. I have been stucked this problem last 7 days.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There `payu-non-seam-less-react` is breaking in the latest version of react native application. I have faced the below issue

```
Error after installing : payu-non-seam-less-react
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/animesh/Developer/experimental/payment_gateway/node_modules/payu-non-seam-less-react/android/build.gradle' line: 141

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':payu-non-seam-less-react'.
> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':payu-non-seam-less-react:androidJavadocJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.

Screenshot of error is also attached,please consider providing a fix. Thank you.
```

to fix this I had made the following changes in node_modules/payu-non-seam-less-react/android/build.gradle

```
   task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
-    classifier = 'javadoc'
+    archiveClassifier = 'javadoc'
     from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
   }
 
   task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
-    classifier = 'sources'
+    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
     from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
   }
```

this is a workaround that may be fixed in the latest build as I have reported the issue to the payu team.

also, there may be some issues with the Android.Manifest file to fix that you have to add the following in the application tag in the manifest file

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
tools:replace="android:theme"
```

- Note: this fix will only be done in the bare react native application.

Hope this will fix your issues.Thank you.